# How to pass string in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want to pass string like this "Andrew's string" or 'Andrew"s string' which contains a single quote or double quotes as a parameter in a javascript function without throwing an exception.

```
var aString="Andrew's String";
var html_string="<a onclick=\"get_settings('hello',''"+aString+");\"></a>";
$("#myDiv").html(html_string);
```

When run this code I got this exception :

JavaScript critical error at line 13, column 54 in (unknown source location)\n\nSCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: "critical error"? All errors are critical :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your code:

In this line:

```
var html_string="<a onclick=\"get_settings('hello',''"+aString+");\"></a>";
```

You use two `'` effectively creating this when parsed:

```
<a onclick="getSettings('hello', ''Andrew's String);"></a>
```

This is the updated version with correct escaping.

```
var aString="Andrew's String";
var html_string="<a onclick=\'get_settings(\"hello\",\""+aString+"\");\'></a>";
$("#myDiv").html(html_string);
```

Personally to avoid problems with unescaped strings altogether I would do this:

```
var aString = "Andrew's String";
var element =  $("<a>Your caption here</a>").click(function(){
    getSettings("hello", aString);
});
$("#myDiv").empty(); //empty the element;
$("#myDiv").append(element);
```

Comment: @epascarello: Only when there's a `"` in the string. Or do you see another error I'm overlooking?

Comment: `onclick="get_settings('hello',"x");"`

Comment: I got another error now, if the string contains ' or "

Comment: @Andrew_Nady, minor bug in it. Try now, I personally recommend the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code by creating div and anchor static into page and handle it using javascript to pass dynamic argument for `hello` and `Andrew's string` as function parameter.

js code:

```
$('#myAnchor').click(function() {
                    get_settings("hello", "Andrew's string");
                });
```

html code:

```
 <div id="myDiv">
            <a id="myAnchor">Click</a>
        </div>
```